# Want crack map as Segmentation mask

Tags: masking, id-mask

I am completely new to Blender and I want your help to get a mask of cracks that I generate on any surface. For my project I need to generate cracks on the object and get on the cracks as an output (which will be segmented). The approach I am trying now is giving me the object surfaces instead of cracks that I generate.

Comment: Have you tried the cell fracture addon? It comes with Blender.

Comment: Yes, I am able to generate cracks on the surface and I want the mask of the generated cracks. In the output I want an image having surface as a background and cracks segmented.